# FileNotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tensorflow, deployment

I am trying to deploy my model. I am encountering the following problem:

> FileNotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed
> to find any matching files for
> ram://a603e930-4fda-4105-8554-7af5e5fc02f5/variables/variables You may
> be trying to load on a different device from the computational device.
> Consider setting the experimental_io_device option in
> `tf.saved_model.LoadOptions` to the io_device such as `'/job:localhost'`

This happened when I stored an NLP model in a pickle. I have seen that it does not work so I then tried to save the model as `.h5` The problem still persists and shows me the above error